# Good books or tutorials for beginning Direct X with c++

Tags: c++, winapi, directx

I'm pretty familiarity with c++. I'v made a few games like tetris and solitaire with it. But what I would really like is some nice textured graphics for those games :-p GDI just isn't doing it for me anymore.

Really, all I would need to know is:

- DX scene initialization
- making something simple like a round rectangle and basic shapes
- ability to move those shapes in X and Y
- add basic bitmap texture
- dispose of the objects

anything  that would cover these concepts would be really useful
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](http://www.directxtutorial.com/Tutorial9/tutorials.aspx) is a good tutorial. I've started with it and it was helpful. That is not a book, but good enough tutorial with step-by-step explanations.

Answer (score 2):

I've got a copy of [Beginning DirectX 10 Game Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1598633619). I haven't done much with it (lack of time, mostly), but it is well-written and covers the basic concepts step-by-step and has the complete code you need to accomplish the tasks in the chapters.

I created a small 2D game (Othello for a school project) using PNGs loaded at run-time, and I could not have done it without the book (I am a complete beginner in Windows and DirectX programming :D).

Answer (score 2):

I would really suggest you to take a look at the [DirectX SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=b66e14b8-8505-4b17-bf80-edb2df5abad4). There are tutorials on how to do all the basic stuff, like initializing a scene, simple primitives, transforming them and texturing them. Once you feel comfortable with that there's a LOT more to dig into, e.g. like how vertex, pixel and geometry shaders work.

Answer (score 2):

[Introduction to 3D Game Programming with Direct X 9.0c: A Shader Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1598220160) by Frank Luna is probably the best "intro" game programming book out there. Enough material to get something interesting on screen and start playing around. I can't recommend it enough.